# Is there a standard way to reset offsets when using the @KafkaListener annotation?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using the KafkaListener Interface in my Spring Boot app, which works just fine. Offsets are stored by Kafka itself.

Now lets say one of the consumers of a topic deploys a new version and screws up 2 hours worth of messages. Then they fix the app and want to start the new version with an offset from two hours ago.

I could use the consumer.seek() with a previous consumer.offsetsForTimes() call, but that is only straighforward when I'm using the polling mechanism, not when using the Spring KafkaListener.

I tried using a ConsumerRebalanceListener, but to set the offsets I need the consumer to be active, which I don't have when instantiating the ConsumerRebalanceListener...

Do I need to switch to polling?
Can I get at the consumer before my KafkaListener is invoked the first time, but after the consumer has been assigned partition(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Not concurrently; the upcoming [2.0 release](https://spring.io/blog/2017/04/27/spring-for-apache-kafka-2-0-milestone-1-available) introduces `ConsumerAwareMessageListener`, which supports passing the `Consumer` as an argument into the `@KafkaListener` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick response.
But what would be the currently suggested method for handling the described scenario? Maybe the replay log producer? (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-ReplayLogProducer) - but I am not able to pass an offset as a range parameter or the like, so that I could have the application process a different topic temporarily.

Comment: I wonder if `ConsumerSeekAware` can help somehow: http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#seek. And you might be need to store an `offset` for processed message to use in the subsequent `ConsumerSeekAware.onPartitionsAssigned()`

Comment: You can implement `ConsumerSeekAware` which allows arbitrary seeks, but because the consumer is not thread safe the callback can only be called during a message delivery or in an application listener when a container idle event is published. However, there's no way to access the `offsetsForTimes` method so you'd need some other way to determine the seek point.